# operator new[] and non POD types

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm trying to overload `operator new` in order to track memory allocations (For debugging). I'm having trouble when allocating arrays of non POD types (e.g. array of a class holding std::string).

It seems like `operator new` is called to allocate memory for the array + 8 bytes that are used to store the array length (probably so that the compiler can call the correct number of destructors when the array is destroyed).

How can `operator new[]` find out whether the actual data will be placed at the returned address (array of PODs) or at the returned address + 8? (I need this so that I can search structures for pointers)

Answer (score 1):

I presume it would do the same way that new[] knows what constructors to call: the compiler tells it. The compiler is keeping track of the data types and knows when it is a POD type or not.

But your real question is not how operator new[] knows or how the compiler knows but how can you find out.

If the object you are allocating is not size 8 then any size requested by new[] that isn't divisible by sizeof(object) would include the count of objects. That might work for you.

The following code sort of seems to work. I am sure there are plenty of ways to break it.

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    int x;
    int y;
};

class B {
    int x;
    int y;
    static int count;
public:
    B() : x(0), y(0) { ++count; }
    ~B() { --count; }
};

int B::count = 0;

template<class T>
T gcd(T a, T b)
{
    T tmp;
    while(b) {
        tmp = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
    return a;
}

void* operator new[](size_t count)
{
    size_t r = gcd(count, sizeof(size_t)*2);
    bool is_counted = r == sizeof(size_t);
    cout << count << " bytes requested and gcd is " << r << ' ' << (is_counted ? "is" : "is not") << " counted\n";
    return ::operator new[](count, std::nothrow);
}

int main()
{
    A* pa = new A[16];
    B* pb = new B[16];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I know the size of the allocated object? Both `operator new` and `operator new[]` are given the total size in bytes and not the size of the individual structure. I guess this is one of those problems with no good solution...

Comment: @nimrodm: I suppose that I was thinking of per-class operator new.

Comment: @nimrodm: The sample code I just added seems to work for classes that are larger than one `size_t`. May or may not help you.